# Compute $\mathbb{E} \left(\min(X, Y) | \max(X, Y) \right)$ for $(X,Y)$ i.i.d. uniform on $(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> Let $X, Y$ be independent random variables with uniform distribution on the interval $[0, 1]$. My task is to find
>   $$\mathbb{E} \big(\min(X, Y) | \max(X, Y) \big).$$

I think it can be done in the following way
$$\mathbb{E} \big(\min(X, Y) | \max(X, Y) \big) = \mathbb{E}\big(\min(X, Y)|\sigma(\max(X,Y) \big) = \mathbb{E}\big(\min(X, Y)|\mathcal{F} \big).$$
Of course $\mathcal{F} = \{ \emptyset, [0,1] \}$ thus $\min(X, Y)$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable. That leads us to
$$\mathbb{E}\big(\min(X, Y)|\mathcal{F} \big) = \min(X, Y).$$
Is my reasoning correct? That won't stand for other distributions will it?

Comment: How did you get $\mathcal F$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It is the $\sigma$-algebra made of $\max(X, Y)$. It's just the new symbol for $\sigma(\max(X,Y))$

Comment: My question is why it is $\{\emptyset, [0,1]\}$. This is not true.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I thought that $\max{X, Y}$ will be $X$ or $Y$. Because both are distributed uniformly thus only two inverse images exist.

Comment: A set like $\{\max (X,Y) < \frac 1 2\} =\{X< \frac 1 2 \text {and} Y< \frac 1 2 \}$ belongs to $\mathcal F$. This set is neither empty nor $[0,1]$ because its probability is $\frac 1 4$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy you're right. How can $\mathcal{F}$ be found then?

Comment: In a less formal way you can state that $\min(X,Y)$ has uniform distritution on $[0,z]$ under the condition that $\max(X,Y)=z$. The corresponding expectation of that distribution is $\frac12z$, leading to the conclusion that $\mathbb E(\min(X,Y)\mid\max(X,Y))=\frac12\max(X,Y)$.

Comment: @drhab Why on the interval $[0,z]$? Both $X$ and $Y$ are constant on the interval [0,1]. Thus only one of them can be the maximum. Or both if they are equal.

Comment: If $\max(X,Y)$ takes value $z\in[0,1]$ (that is the *condition* I pose) then $min(X,Y)$ will definitely take some value on interval $[0,z]$. Further under the mentioned condition it will have uniform distribution on $[0,z]$ so that its expectation under that condition is $\frac12z$. This is true for every $z\in[0,1]$.

Comment: "Both X and Y are constant on the interval [0,1]" ?? This, and other remarks that you made, seem to point at a fundamental misunderstanding, either of the notion of distribution, or of sigma-algebra generated by a random variable, or of something else, but I cannot quite pinpoint what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

drhab has already commented how to informally derive the solution. I will formally prove that this is in fact the correct solution.

To this end, let $Z = \max(X,Y)$. We want to show
$$
E[\min(X,Y)|\sigma(Z)] = \frac{Z}{2} \quad \text{a.s.}
$$

The right hand side is obviously $\sigma(Z)$-measurable. So all we need to show is
$$
E[\min(X,Y)\mathbb{1}_F] = E\left[\frac{Z}{2}\mathbb{1}_F\right]
$$
for all $F \in \sigma(Z)$.

We will show this property for $F = \{Z \leq a \}$ with $a \in \mathbb{R}$. This is enough because these sets form a $\pi$-system (meaning it's $\cap$-stable) generating $\sigma(Z)$ and we can use a dynkin system argument to get the property for all $F \in \sigma(Z)$. Let me know if I should go into more detail here.

Because $X$ and $Y$ are iid $U([0,1])$, $Z$ has the Lebesgue density $f_Z(z) = 2z\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(z)$. So we get for the right hand side
$$
E\left[\frac{Z}{2}\mathbb{1}_F\right] = \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^azdP^Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^a z^2 \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(z)dz\\
=
\begin{cases}
0 \quad &a < 0\\
\frac13 a^3 \quad &a \in [0,1]\\
\frac13 \quad &a > 1
\end{cases}.
$$

For the left hand side, we get, using the symmetry of $X$ and $Y$ and $F = \{Z \leq a \} = \{X \leq a \} \cap \{Y \leq a \}$,
$$
E[\min(X,Y)\mathbb{1}_F] = 2E[\min(X,Y)\mathbb{1}_F\mathbb{1}_{\{X \leq Y\}}] = 2E[X \mathbb{1}_{\{X \leq a\}}\mathbb{1}_{\{Y \leq a\}}\mathbb{1}_{\{X \leq Y\}}]\\
= 2\int_0^1\int_0^1 x \mathbb{1}_{\{x \leq a\}} \mathbb{1}_{\{y \leq a\}}\mathbb{1}_{\{x \leq y\}} dy dx\\
= 2 \int_0^1 x \mathbb{1}_{\{x \leq a\}} \int_x^1 \mathbb{1}_{\{y \leq a\}} dy dx.
$$
Now you can distinguish the same $3$ cases as above and notice that you arrive at the same values.

Comment: (+1) The phrase "a $\cap$-stable generator of $\sigma(Z)$" could be replaced by the more standard "a $\pi$-system generating $\sigma(Z)$.